# Registering native routines: why null-terminate arrays?

Tags: r, r-package

[Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines) says to null-terminate external interface arrays. Examples and CRAN packages ([dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/src/init.cpp#L124), [stringi](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/blob/master/src/stri_stringi.cpp#L240) + comment, [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/src/init.c#L143)) all include `{NULL, NULL, 0}`.

The following `foo` package passes R CMD check, no notes.

```r
bar = \(x) .Call(c_bar, x)
```

```c
#include <Rinternals.h>
int bar(SEXP baz) {return TYPEOF(baz);}
static const R_CallMethodDef entries[] = {
    {"c_bar", (DL_FUNC) &bar, 1} // No {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

void R_init_foo(DllInfo* dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, entries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

**Question**: Why is `{NULL, NULL, 0}` required / recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of `R_registerRoutines` in `src/main/Rdynload.c` ([link](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/Rdynload.c)) is helpful:

```c
    if(callRoutines) {
        for(num = 0; callRoutines[num].name != NULL; num++) {;}
        info->CallSymbols =
            (Rf_DotCallSymbol*)calloc((size_t) num, sizeof(Rf_DotCallSymbol));
        info->numCallSymbols = num;
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
            R_addCallRoutine(info, callRoutines+i, info->CallSymbols + i);
    }
```

Here, `callRoutines` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `R_CallMethodDef` structs.  By not terminating the array with a "null struct", you are relying on undefined behaviour in the second loop iteration at `callRoutines[num].name != NULL`, where the array is indexed out of bounds.